# Train System.Speech.Recognition to recognize audio commands

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, system.speech.recognition

I have an idea for a simple application that will use voice activated commands. It is basically a voice activated dictaphone. I need two voice commands, one for start recording and one for stop recording. I was thinking of using System.Speech.Recognition, i found an example where you can type in a command as string in english, something like this:

```
Choices ch_StartStopCommands = new Choices();
    ch_StartStopCommands.Add("speech on");
    ch_StartStopCommands.Add("speech off");
```

What i want is for the commands to not be language specific. I want to give user the option to say (record via microphone) a command that will be used as a Start Command and another one for a Stop Command.

So my question is basically can i use System.Speech.Recognition to store what user recorded for his start command, and then listen for the same command later on and initiate voice recording until he sais the stop command?

If anyone knows a better speach recognition package for this usecase, i will accept that as an answer also.

Thanks